# How do I use SpriteKit's SKAction to create a time interval for an SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a function, basketball. I want to be able to spawn my basketBall node at CGPoint(515,700), the top of the screen, in a regular time interval. The only method I knew that would accomplish waiting a few seconds was sleep(); however, sleep() apparently doesn't allow SpriteNodes to remain on screen, so I need an alternative.

I discovered NSTimeInterval, but I would prefer to refrain from importing Foundation. I think that SKAction allows time to pass through waitForDuration(), but I am very confused as to how that works. Can someone shed some light on SpriteKit's SKAction?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let basketBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basketball")
    let waitForObjects = SKAction.waitForDuration(3)
    let basketBallFalls = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.Basketball()
    })
    let action = SKAction.sequence([waitForObjects, basketBallFalls])


    SKAction.runAction(action, onChildWithName: "basketball")
    SKAction.repeatActionForever(action)
    //Basketball()
}

func Basketball(){

    basketBall.position = CGPointMake(515, 700)
    basketBall.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
    basketBall.size = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    basketBall.zPosition = 10
    basketBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25.0)
    basketBall.physicsBody?.mass = 0.8
    basketBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.6
    basketBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true


    self.addChild(basketBall)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`SKAction.waitForDuration(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/).

Ex. something like this:

```
let waitDuration = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(20))

let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(waitDuration)
let ballAction = SKAction.runBlock(self.Basketball) //call your function

runAction(SKAction.sequence([waitAction, ballAction]))
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two straightforward ways to spawn a new node at a regular interval. They both involve your scene.

The scene's [`update(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/update:) method is called every frame, and the argument is the current time. Add an `NSTimeInterval` property to your scene class which will store the last time you created a basketball. In `update(_:)`, subtract the current time from the last spawn time. If the difference is greater than the interval that you want, spawn a new node and keep the new current time.

Your scene can also run actions, like any other node. `SKAction` has a [`waitForDuration(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/waitForDuration:) method which creates an action that does, well, exactly what its name says. You can create another action using [`SKAction.runBlock(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock:) which will perform the spawning. Then create [a sequence action](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:) that runs the delay action followed by the spawn action. Wrap that in a [`repeatActionForever(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/repeatActionForever:), and finally tell your scene to run the repeater action.